# Download file rename when return file name videoplayback

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl, download

how to i rename file when link call back videoplayback and title id is `$t`
and url http://www.example.com/api/download.php?id=videoid&itag=tag&t=title back when file save name videoplayback how to i change this name with &t=title
i tried this

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$itag=$_GET['itag'];
$t=$_GET['t'];
header("Location: " . 'http://example.com/api/'.$id.'/direct/'.$itag.'/'); //this is a redirect code
die();
```

Comment: @iliev Thanks for suggest

Comment: Your Question is hard to understand... what do you want to do? Can you describe it more precisely?

Comment: when any one click on video download link file name return `videoplayback` i want to change return name with `$t`

Comment: But your above code doesn't show anything of a file, it's just a URL-rewrite?!

Comment: when code is redirect 302 return file `videoplayback`

Comment: sorry, I'm not getting the point...

Comment: please visit this site uplaytube.com and watch video top of the video player click on download file return videoplayback of mp4

Comment: The file is downloaded from `'http://ytapi.com/api/'.$id.'/direct/'.$itag.'/'`? Is this your API? Or is this a data-provider?

Comment: @sergej data provider

Comment: Then you can do nothing... ytapi must provide a possibility to rename the file but you won't be able, because the file isn't transfered via your server.

Comment: The only thing you can do is to download it on your server, rename it and provide it then to the user, but this will be not performant...